# Select the highest root of the list

Tags: filtering

How can I select the highest root of the list?
I was working to find only the root with the highest value.

```
{{B -> 0.622096}, {B -> 1.03445}, {B -> 48.6767}}
```

I want to apear only

```
{{B -> 48.6767}} or {B -> 48.6767}
```

Comment: See `Sort` and `Maximum`.

Answer (score 11):

Perfect case for [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) and the operator form of [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html).

```
roots = {{B -> 0.622096}, {B -> 1.03445}, {B -> 48.6767}};

MaximalBy[roots, Lookup[B]]
(* {{B -> 48.6767}} *)
```

Comment: Or `MaximalBy[roots, Last]`

Comment: In this case even `MaximalBy[roots, Identity]` works too.

Comment: Or `MaximalBy[roots, Values]`.

Answer (score 7):

```
roots /. soln // Max
```

Works and uses core functions.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
expr = {{B -> 0.622096}, {B -> 1.03445}, {B -> 48.6767}};
B -> Max[Transpose[expr][[1]] /. Rule[B, x_] -> x]
(*  B -> 48.6767  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

```
roots = {{B -> 0.622096}, {B -> 1.03445}, {B -> 48.6767}};

ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]

f1 = Merge[Max];
f2 = Last @* Sort;
f3 = #[[Ordering[#, -1]]] &;


f1 @ roots
```

> ```
> <|B -> 48.6767|>
> ```

If you need a list:

```
Normal @ %
```

> ```
> {B -> 48.6767}
> ```

```
f2  @ roots
```

> ```
> {B -> 48.6767}
> ```

```
f3 @ roots
```

> ```
> {{B -> 48.6767}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I like the neat functionality of `Ordering`:

```
Extract[#,Ordering[#,-1]]&@roots
```

> `{B->48.6767}`

If you prefer `Cases`:

```
Cases[#,List[Rule[b_,Max@Values@#]]]&@roots
```

> `{{B->48.6767}}`

Answer (score 3):

Using [`TakeLargestBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeLargestBy.html)

```
roots = {{B -> 0.622096}, {B -> 1.03445}, {B -> 48.6767}};

TakeLargestBy[roots, #[[-1, -1]] &, 1]
(* {{B -> 48.6767}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `PositionLargest` (since 13.2):

```
roots = {{B -> 0.622096}, {B -> 1.03445}, {B -> 48.6767}};

Extract[PositionLargest[roots[[All, 1, 2]]]] @ list
```

{B -> 48.6767}

To get the two largest roots:

```
Extract[PositionLargest[roots[[All, 1, 2]], 2]] @ list
```

{{B -> 48.6767}, {B -> 1.03445}}